Spectral distributions in Gram matrices built from unit random vectors in high dimensions (and relation to LLM embeddings)

I am wondering if any rigorous mathematical results are known for the following:
${V}_i \in \mathbb{R}^d$ ($i=1,2,\ldots N$) are randomly-distributed unit vectors, $\| V_i\| =1$.

Consider the following symmetric real matrix of ordinary "dot-products" of the random vectors:
$$
G_{ij} = \left( {V}_i, {V}_j \right)
$$ $-$ the Gram matrix.
Let $\lambda_k$, $k=1,2,\ldots, N$ be the eigenvalues of the Gram matrix in the ascending order and $\Delta_k = \lambda_{k+1} - \lambda_k$ are the spectral gaps.
Are there any rigorous results about the distribution of the spectral gaps $P[\Delta]$ in the case where both $N \leq d$ and $d$ are large? If $N>d$ the determinant of the Gram matrix is zero (because it calculates the volume formed by the vectors) and so there are $N-d$ zero eigenvalues.

A practically relevant case is vector embeddings of large language models (LLMs), which involve a mapping of (e.g., semantic) content into a "vector" of unit length. The commercial LLM embeddings involve large dimensions (e.g., $d=1536$ for the smallest Open AI embedding), which encode the semantic meaning. It's interesting to characterize distributions for different types of data, but it has to be done relative to the base (featureless/random) distribution and I'd like to know what it is.

I originally expected GOE Wigner-Dyson, but I do not see it. Perhaps, the fact that the vectors lie on a sphere imply that there are $N$ "hidden conservation laws" in the "Hamiltonian" (the Gram matrix) and so it is more like an integrable system, which would then suggest Poisson statistics per Berry conjecture. But I do not know if it's the right intuition, so rigorous results, if exist, would help.


